# Android calling Android function fron JavaScript using javascriptInterface

Tags: android, android-webview

I try to call a java function from an html file but I can't.
I tried to add a thread on my javascriptInterface class but the application crash. ( nullPointer )
I understand that when a java function is called by the javascript it doens't run on the same thread.

How the communication between the javascript and java should be done ?
I can't do anything even on the javascriptInterface. I can't call a function even if it is on the javascriptInterface

Here is my code :

**javascriptInterface.java**

```
public class javascriptInterface {  
    Context mContext;
    WebView webView;

    javascriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getTextMenuBarJS(String text){ 
        webView.getTextMenuBar(i,text);
    }
}
```

**webview.java**

public class WebView extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    webViewContent.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){}); 

    webViewContent.loadUrl(JsonParsing.jsonObjectMap.get("path"));


    webViewContent.addJavascriptInterface(new javascriptInterface(this), "Android");

    btnSimple = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);
    btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            webView.loadUrl("" +
                    "javascript:" +
                    "(function() {" +
                    "var NumberChildrenMenuBar = document.getElementById('menubar').childElementCount;"+
                    "var menubar = document.getElementById('menubar');"+
                    "var MenuHTMLContent;"+
                    "for(var i=0; i<NumberChildrenMenuBar;i++){MenuHTMLContent = menubar.children[i].outerHTML; window.Android.getHTMLMenuBarJS(i,MenuHTMLContent);}"+

                    "})();"); 
               }
            });
       }

       public void getTextMenuBar(final int i,final String text){   
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() { 
                     //load a function
                 }
             });
        }
```

And here is the error I always have :

```
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at com. ... . ... .javascriptInterface$2.run(javascriptInterface.java:44)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-29 15:25:02.030: E/AndroidRuntime(27323):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are initialising the WebView field in the javaScriptInterface class, yet you call a method on that variable in getTextMenuBarJS(). That will cause a null pointer exception.

I suspect you mean to also pass the WebView instance in the javaScriptInterface constructor.

Comment: getTextMenuBarJS doesn't cause a null pointer. I would like to modify a static string[] from the webview activity. The null pointer comes when I for example WebView.valueReceived.add(text); How should I initialize the webview field ?

Comment: Pass it in in the constructor of javaScriptInterface (the same place that you set the Context) seems reasonable. Sounds like there is some code missing from your initial post, that makes it hard to diagnose the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error was coming from the javascriptInterface
I changed it to have something like that

```
public class JavaScriptHandler {

    WebView webview;

    public JavaScriptHandler(WebView activity) {
        webview = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void JSfunction(String[] text){ 
        this.webview.dosomething();
    }

}
```

And on the activity I have

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(this), "Android");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {"+ window.Android.JSfunction(); +"})();");
```

Comment: Intent not working from JavascriptInterface. Do you have any idea?